# BEGIN...END vs START TRANSACTION...COMMIT

Tags: mysql

What is the difference between doing:

```
START TRANSACTION
...
COMMIT
```

Or doing:

```
BEGIN
...
END
```

Does the later autocommit, or what might be a practical example of using one of the other?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: The version is....5.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In both MySQL 5.7 and MySQL 8, `BEGIN` and `END` is the same as in T-SQL and represents a "compound statement"  also known as "a block of code", just like curly-braces in C, Java, C#, etc.

- MySQL 5.7: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/begin-end.html
- MySQL 8.0: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/begin-end.html

[However, the `BEGIN` keyword **is also** (confusingly) overloaded as an alias for `BEGIN WORK` and `START TRANSACTION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html), and their semantics depend on if they're being used inside a stored program or not:

> Within all stored programs (stored procedures and functions, triggers, and events), the parser treats `BEGIN [WORK]` as the beginning of a `BEGIN ... END` block. Begin a transaction in this context with `START TRANSACTION` instead.

So:

- `START TRANSACTION`

  - Always starts a transaction. You should prefer this syntax.
- `BEGIN`:

  - If you're in a Stored Procedure, Function, Trigger or Event, then `BEGIN` by itself marks the start of a compound statement. You can only use `START TRANSACTION` to start a transaction.
  - If you're directly executing SQL against MySQL, then this also starts a transaction (as it's interpreted as `BEGIN WORK`). But it's silly and confusing to use it this way, so avoid it.
- `BEGIN WORK`:

  - This is an alias for `START TRANSACTION`. I'd avoid using this completely to prevent confusion.

Comment: thanks for this great explanation. Though, I must admit I'm still a bit confused on it! It seems like there's a real usage of using `begin...end` in mysql8.0? But for mysql5.7 I could just as well leave it out and use start/end transation when I need something like that, correct?

Comment: @David542 As far as I can tell, the syntax and semantics are the same in both 5.7 and 8.0 (when I started writing my answer I assumed things were different between 5.7 and 8.0, but now (after reading all their documentation) I don't think there's any difference in behaviour between 5.7 and 8.0.

Comment: Then , is it possible to have `... BEGIN ... START TRANSACTION ... COMMIT ... END...` ?. I means to have a transaction within a `BEGIN ...END`

Comment: @christianbueno.1 Yes, you can. Don't forget to `ROLLBACK` on error though.